# Passing selected variables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send some information from one php file to another.
I've read about the use of `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`, but they're giving me some problems.

My code looks something like this:

```
<form action="booking.php" method="post">
<select name="bookingflight">
<?php
    $query =   "SELECT Flight, Name
                FROM Airport";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"". $row['Flight'] . ',' . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['Flight'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select></p>

<input type="submit" value="book flight"/>
</form>
```

This gives me a dropbox list of all the flights, along with the name of the flights.
If I select an element it's stored in `$_POST["bookingflight"]` which I can access in `booking.php`, which is fine.

However, it's given as a string, while I should be able to handle flight and name separately.
Ideally, I'd have two variables, one for flight and one for name, which I can access in `booking.php`.

How should I do this?  With `$_SESSION` I don't even know how to assign a selected item from the list to a variable.

Comment: Then read PHP manual - http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: if any of `Flight` or `name` data is unique then just pass that unique data in option `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternate Solution:** If `Flight` is unique data

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$flight=$row['Flight'];
$name=$row['Name'];
          echo "<option value='$flight'>$flight $name</option>";
    }
```

**PHP :** booking.php

```
<?php
$flight=$_POST['bookingflight'];
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Flight,Name FROM Airport WHERE Flight='$flight'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$name= $row['Name'] ; // Here you get Name of selected Flight


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Or** 
If your `Airport` table contains any unique data/id , you can pass that data as option `value` too

Answer (score 1):

You started this the wrong way...

Give your Airport table a unique primary key (named id, INT, auto-increment) and pass that as a value in generated options:

```
echo "<option value=\"". $row['id'] ."\">" . $row['Flight'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

Now when you POST your form you get that ID value in booking.php.
Because every flight has a unique ID you can just issue another query and you get your result as an array there:

```
$query = "SELECT Flight, Name FROM Airport WHERE id = $id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your booking.php...

```
if($_POST)

{


$values = $_POST['bookingflight'];

$val= explode(',',$values);


$_SESSION['flightnumber'] = $val[0];

$_SESSION['flightname'] = $val[1];



}
```